# Multi nested model driven form angular 2

Tags: angular2-forms, formbuilder, form-control, formgroups

I'm working with ionic 2 angular 2. I want to know that how to create a multi-nested **formgroup** in html template.

**For example:**

this is form group in **.ts** file

```
HomeAddress: this.formBuilder.group({
    Address: ['', Validators.required]
    HomeAddressDetail: this.formBuilder.group({
        Country: ['', Validators.required]
        Tel: this.formBuilder.group({
            PhoneNo: ['', Validators.required],
            HomeNo: ['', Validators.required]
        }),
        Email: this.formBuilder.group({
            PrimaryEmail: ['', Validators.required],
            SecondaryEmail: ['', Validators.required]
        })
    })
});
```

How can I set the HTML template according to this **FormGroup.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the HTML template like bellow:

```
<form [formGroup]="HomeAddress">
     <div>Address: <input type="text" formControlName="Address"></div>
     <div formGroupName="HomeAddressDetail">
         <div>Country: <input type="text" formControlName="Country"></div>
         <div formGroupName="Tel">
              Phone No: <input type="text" formControlName="PhoneNo">
              Home No: <input type="text" formControlName="HomeNo">
         </div>
         <div formGroupName="Email">
              Primary Email: <input type="text" formControlName="PrimaryEmail">
              Secondary Email: <input type="text" formControlName="SecondaryEmail">
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I dont know the ionic controls, I replied in angular 2. You can use same format in ionic 2. Here is the plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/SMCAMddPNmEyHuVS0IK8?p=preview

Comment: Now Tel is Undefined.

Comment: vendor.js:1703 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find control with name: 'Tel'

Comment: included plunkr. please check